# Some cucumber methods do not work correctly (Cucumber Feature Wrapper)

Tags: java, testing, cucumber, testng, cucumber-java

I have a question about Cucumber library, I was taking a course of selenium with cucumber and testNg, but I have run into some problems because some methods no longer exist

For Example:

- I cant used "CucumberFeatureWrapper" what could be the relative to this? **Image:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JMcD.png
- The same way happens when i need to used .provideFeatures(); in testNgCucumberRunner.provideFeatures **Image:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/L76xQ.png

POM:

```
e<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>CRMFramework</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>10</source>
                <target>10</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/TestNg.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>

                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectName>ExecuteAutomation</projectName>
                        <!-- output directory for the generated report -->
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-reports</outputDirectory>
                        <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-json-report.json</inputDirectory>
                        <jsonFiles>
                            <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                            <param>**/*.json</param>
                        </jsonFiles>
                        <mergeFeaturesWithRetest>true</mergeFeaturesWithRetest>
                        <mergeFeaturesById>true</mergeFeaturesById>
                        <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                        <skipEmptyJSONFiles>true</skipEmptyJSONFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jxl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/datatable-dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>datatable-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

TestRunner

```
import com.aventstack.extentreports.gherkin.model.Feature;
import com.crm.framework.utilities.ExtentReport;
import io.cucumber.testng.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

import java.util.List;

//json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumberTestReport.json
@CucumberOptions(
    features = {"src/test/java/features/"},
    glue = {"steps"},
    plugin = {"json:target/cucumber-json-report.json",
            "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-report-html"})
public class TestRunner {

private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void setUpClass() {
    testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
}

@Test(dataProvider = "features")
public void LoginTest(CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeatureWrapper) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    //Insert the Feature Name
    //ExtentReport.startFeature("login").assignAuthor("DiegoHM").assignDevice("Chrome").assignCategory("Regression");

}

@DataProvider
public Object[] features(ITestContext context) {
    // return testNGCucumberRunner.
    return testNGCucumberRunner.provideFeatures();
    
}

@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void afterClass() {
    testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're using classes that don't exist anymore. You can find out which classes are in a library by using  ctrl/cmd + clicking on a package name in most modern IDEs.

So try using:

```java
package io.cucumber.examples.testng;

import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.testng.FeatureWrapper;
import io.cucumber.testng.PickleWrapper;
import io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


@CucumberOptions(....)
public class RunCucumberByCompositionTest {

    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Scenarios", dataProvider = "scenarios")
    public void scenario(PickleWrapper pickle, FeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickle.getPickle());
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() {
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }

}
```

From:
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/examples/java-calculator-testng/src/test/java/io/cucumber/examples/testng