# unable to import CucumberFeatureWrapper in my TestRunner class in Cucumber

Tags: java, testng, cucumber-java

I am trying to set up the Cucumber+TestNG framework for Java.

```
@Test(dataProvider = "features")
public void feature(CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature){
    testNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(cucumberFeature);
}
```

CucumberFeatureWrapper class is not loading/importing properly.

I have the latest Maven dependency for Cucumber-TestNG:
as follows:

```html
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

, it seems like that class is missing from jar file. (as below)

[image]

---

my question would be, was  class deprecated or something?

Hope anyone give me any advice how to resolve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66067292/some-cucumber-methods-do-not-work-correctly-cucumber-feature-wrapper

Comment: Thank you @AlexeyR. That explains why it didn't import properly. do you happen to know what class replaced that class in the most recent versions? or was it not needed? I am combining Cucumber with TestNG for the first time, not sure what is the proper way to combine these two powerful tools.